# How do I compile Oracle SQL scripts?

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file

I have a series of SQL files, and I want to compile all of them.  If do them manually by using benthic software, it takes a long time.  I tried using TOAD, but I don't like to use cracked software.  Can you help me execute a SQL file?  I want to write a program to do some things for me.

From sql/plus I tried to create batch file but in some of my sql file developer used "/" and ";" so it caused sql/plus suddenly stopping the compilation.  Please advise or recommend free software to help.

"I want apply the sql package , function and if they are invalid compile them again"

I am using oracle 10g.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you search for something like TOAD, try [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/index.html), a free tool from Oracle.
- If you want to recompile existing source in your database, you can use [`dbms_utility.compile_schema`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_util.htm#i1002332).
- If you try to install several files in a batch, [SQL*Plus](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ) should work for you. Make sure that your files have the right format.

Comment: how I can use Sql developer?I already have itbut I dont have any idea how I can compile 900 sql file? in TOAD i just paste all file address and press run,how is it in sql developer.would u explain more?

Comment: I tried to create a batchfile and run in sqlplus but some of my files not following right format, that's why in middle of compilation it will stop...

Comment: SQL is an interpreted language, there is no "compile". Do you mean PL/SQL? That is, 900 files worth of PL/SQL functions, procedures, and packages? Also, there's a free version of Toad that might work for you.

Comment: @rima: I would use SQL*Plus to execute 900 files. What format do you have in your files that can be executed via TOAD, but not via SQL*Plus? And why can't you fix these files?

Comment: @jim: free software of toad!?? where?I mean PL/SQL contain package/function and procedures.

Comment: @petter: in some pl/sql file developer used ; and /  together pl/sql can not handle / at end of file or when we use them together...

Comment: @rima: In this case you have to fix your source files. While this might take some time, you only have to do it once, and then you can install everything with just one call of SQL*Plus.

Comment: The Toad freeware is at http://www.toadworld.com/Freeware/tabid/680/Default.aspx. Usable for up to 5 seats, expires every 90 days and you need to re-download.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to run a large sql script.  Correct?  Sql/Plus should work, but if you want a free IDE, I recommend SQL Developer.  It isn't perfect, but it is one of the better free solutions.

Comment: they are around 900 sql package, in this case how? and how I can see which one in valid and which one is not valid?also plz read above comment

Answer (score 1):

"in some of my sql file developer used "/" and ";" "

You need to consistently use these to have any hope of using a tool to deploy. You don't want to have to use a GUI to deploy, so SQL*Plus is the standard to aim for. A good Oracle GUI should be able to run a SQL*Plus deployment script.

I generally start with SET DEFINE OFF otherwise unexpected ampersands (&) cause issues.
Do some basic grepping - any script with a CREATE PACKAGE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE TRIGGER or CREATE TYPE (including CREATE OR REPLACE) should have a the "/" to execute that statement. If they don't, fix them.

For a first run though, I'd take them in batches of 10, until I was sure that they executed correctly. I wouldn't worry about compilation errors as long as they load. Afterwards, you can do a recompile of any invalid objects in the schema.

Then check USER_ERRORS to see what is still broken.